# Nested Loops and API calls

Tags: powerapps

I'm building an application to add employee activities to our ERP, and then assign attendees to those activities.

First I have to make a call to our ERP to add an activity, which then returns the Activity ID from ERP. Then using that, I'm supposed to add all of the attendees to the activity.

Theres multiple activities that can have multiple attendees.

During the process, I'm saving all of the Activities to a table in my database, and Attendees to another table (and they're connected by activity_id field in Attendees table.

Then I make a call to get AllActivities into a collection to loop through.

This is what I currently have:

```
    ForAll(
    AllActivities;
    Collect(
        AddedActivity;
        'MyApi'.AddActivitiesToBusinessPartner(
            {
        }
        )
    );;
    ForAll(
        Filter(
            '[dbo].[attendees]';
            activity_id = AllActivities[@id]
        );
        'MyApi'.AddAttendantsToAnExistingActivity(
            {

            }
        )
    )
)
```

So basically: 
1. add activity
2. get ID from the ERP
3. loop trough database and see if there's attendees
4. add attendees to ERP

The second ForAll is not executing at all.

Comment: so you are trying achieve what is called "chaining action" in PowerApps.
you have added ;; after your first ForAll.
How about rather than ;; you just try only ;
Here is one thread which tells why ;; does not work https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Multiple-actions-in-a-formula/td-p/19663

Comment: Also after your first ForAll how about you just add another simple statement rather than next ForAll. Why I am saying is below thread



https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Chaining-operation-doesn-t-work-Expected-an-operator/td-p/237788

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked (I also posted on the powerapps forums and got help there): https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Nested-Loops-and-API-calls/m-p/315045#M90564